# JVM: what language can be used for JVM instruction implementation?

Tags: java, jvm, native, bytecode

Taken from official [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html) documentation on JVM:

> An implementation of the Java Virtual Machine may use conventional stacks, colloquially called "C stacks," to support native methods (methods written in a language other than the Java programming language). Native method stacks may also be used by the implementation of an interpreter for the Java Virtual Machine's instruction set in a language such as C.

So, basically whenever JVM implements its instruction set in C then the implementation can use native method stack. This makes me think about what other languages can JVM instruction set be implemented in and what kind of stack is used in those cases ?

Comment: The whole point of defining a VM is that _theoretically_ it can be implemented in any way you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, basically whenever JVM implements its instruction set in C then the implementation can use native method stack.

The JVM spec says that when the JVM is implemented in "a language *such as* C" (emphasis added) it may use so called "C stacks".  This is very nearly meaningless.    The most plausible interpretation is that if the implementation of the language with which a particular JVM is itself implemented relies on C stacks, then that JVM itself is permitted to rely on C stacks.

The context of the quote is a discussion of memory areas used by the JVM, so the main point being made is simply that the JVM may devote some of its runtime memory to C stacks.  An entirely separate provision is made for the Java stack, though the specification does not require that this is distinct from the area for C stacks in a JVM that uses C stacks.

Note, however, that although one would ordinarily expect C itself to be considered a language such as C, its specification has nothing whatever to say about stacks.  "C stacks" are not a property of C, but rather of hardware and ABI.

> This makes me think about what other languages can JVM instruction set be implemented in

The JVM can, in principle, be implemented in any Turing-complete language.  Examples include C, C++, Fortran, Python, Lisp, Perl, Ruby, Bash, BASIC, Java itself, and many others, past, present, and future.  Some are more attractive candidates than others.

> and what kind of stack is used in those cases ?

If the chosen implementation of the chosen language uses C stacks, then the JVM *may* reserve space for C stacks.  There is also the Java stack, which every JVM has.  The JVM spec does not make explicit provision for any other kind of stack.

Comment: Thank you fir the reply! Just a small clarification, `though the specification does not require that this is distinct from the area for C stacks in a JVM that uses C stacks` does this mean that internally Java stack and C stack may share same memory area ? Did I got the quote correctly or missed something ?

Comment: @jonnyB_5531, yes, you have interpreted my words as I intended them.  Do understand, however, that my comment is an observation that the JVM does not forbid that arrangement, not that the spec explicitly endorses it.

Comment: In fact, I suspect that part of the point of the spec explicitly mentioning C stacks is actually the reverse: to avoid implying that the Java stack must be implemented via a C stack, even when the JVM implementation language itself relies on C stacks.